# Why don't Avro auto-generated classes implement Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, avro

Is there a technical reason why Avro's auto-generated Java classes don't implement `java.io.Serializable`? It seems the classes are data objects composed of basic data types and other Avro auto-generated classes, and it should be trivial to generate them compatible with Java serialization. Is it just something that nobody thought of (hard to believe, given how ubiquitous Java serialization is) or bothered doing (again hard to believe given that it just requires the class generator to spit out two additional words)? Or is there a technical reason for this limitation?

I mention this because from time to time I run Spark jobs on Avro data objects only to have them fail because I forgot to switch from Java to Kryo serialization. Each time I scratch my head wondering why.

Comment: According to the docs: Java serialization: By default, Spark serializes objects using Java’s ObjectOutputStream framework, and can work with any class you create that implements java.io.Serializable. You can also control the performance of your serialization more closely by extending java.io.Externalizable. Java serialization is flexible but often quite slow, and leads to large serialized formats for many classes. I am scratching my head.

Comment: @thebluephantom I understand how Spark works but this question isn't about Spark, it's about Avro. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: May be I should read better.